# How to get Poker Night at the Inventory's "Slow Play" achievement?

Tags: achievements, poker-night-at-the-inventory

I have been playing Poker Night at the Inventory for some six hours now, and I cannot figure out how to get the Slow Play achievement.  The description, "Check a pat hand" is vague to say the least.  I've looked into pat hands but can't find any true definition in relation to Texas hold'em.  Also, how iron-clad is the "check" part of that statement.  Would calling another player's bet count, or not?  All-in-all, some real rules around this achievement would be great, not hearsay.

### Update from 10/15/2014 play

I was playing last night with pocket 9 and K of hearts.  I called.  On the flop a 3, 4, and J of hearts was dealt.  Max bet $2,300 or so and I called.  No achievement.

Comment: Based on your update, it sounds like the "check" is the key there, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I agree, that seems overly restrictive though, raising, I would understand, but calling?  Perhaps it isn't meant to be restrictive but suffers from some sort of coding fail...  Time, or another user, will tell.

Answer (score 2):

A "pat hand" is a draw poker term, but in this case, it seems to refer to a hand that is very likely to win.

So, instead of raising when you have a Flush or Straight, check/call instead.

Now... it's been a while since I've played the game, but I'm going to assume that calling counts for this achievement... or any other action that isn't raising.

Comment: I've seen some references that you must have a five card winning hand after the flop to qualify for this achievement, so a full house would count, but two pairs, three of a kind, or even four of a kind wouldn't be a "pat hand".  I'm hoping someone has had some experience to confirm or deny that.  Unfortunately, it also seems like speculation regarding calling...  I'd love to trial and error the achievement but that's practically impossible.

Answer (score 1):

As Powerlord says, a pat hand is a winning hand.

A pair in the pocket isn't sufficient. I've had lots of pairs (including aces) that I'd check, without getting the achievement. Since this is the highest hand you could have with two, Slow Play has to come after the flop.

You can get Slow Play on the turn (the fourth shared card); it doesn't have to be right after the flop. I got it on a flush.